# Clear required/not null bound textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a problem with a bound textbox. The field is **required** and don't allow **Null** in the database.

This gives me a problem when I want to clear the textbox. For example if I entered something and deleted it then the validation rule kicks in and don't allow me to leave the field. I can only leave the field if I hit ESC so reset it to its original (unaltered) state.

I tried setting the field to `Nothing` and `DefaultValue` in an `_After-/_BeforeUpdate()`  event but that doesn't work.

*Thank you for your help.*

Comment: So what would you want the behaviour to be? It's been a while since I've developed MS Access but I always use to use Unbound forms and then have SQL scripts that run when a Save button is clicked. Effectively seperating the interface from the data.

Comment: What is the point of having not null if you do not want it to work? The correct behaviour is to revert to the original value. If you want nulls, set it that way.

Comment: Exactly as Remou says, you can't tell it not to allow nulls and then try and test it's patience with them ^_^ What would you like the end result to be as then we can advise the best option?

Comment: I want the field to have the unaltered state so I can leave the field. The work around I got now is to allow nulls in the database and check for nulls when they try to submit the form. But that could cause the database to have bad data if I forget to check for nulls somewhere.

Comment: If you want the unaltered state, use undo. If nulls are not allowed, leave it that way, that is the whole point of a database. Do not change a correctly designed database to make the front-end work. If the database is not correctly designed, that is another story.

Comment: @Snæbjørn It would require a little more work on your part but you could always sort this out by using an unbound form (as creamyegg mentioned), this would not force you to do anything at form level but would still require validation before submitting the form.

Comment: Ye, I guess that would be the best approach. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but is it possible to get the validationrule for a database field? Cause then I something like this MyField.ValidationRule = [Table]![Column].ValidationRule

Comment: I agree with @creamyegg and Matt in that unbinding the form then posting with SQL will prevent this type of error from occurring (assuming you run the proper checks before executing).

Comment: What version of Access are you using? Access 2010 has data macros. However, I think the main problem is that you need to decide whether or not the field is required.

Comment: @Gaffi What error? If the database field is set to required and not null, there is no error. The form is simply preventing an error occurring. Unbinding the form will allow you to submit a form with an error that you then have to handle elsewhere.

Comment: @Remou, ok, not programmatic 'error', but experienced 'problem'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this, thanks to the comments, was using an unbound textbox and then copying the validation rule from the database in the form `On Load` procedure.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.MyTextbox.ValidationRule = CurrentDb.TableDefs("SomeTable").Fields("SomeColumn").ValidationRule & " Or Is Null"
    Me.MyTextbox.ValidationText = CurrentDb.TableDefs("SomeTable").Fields("SomeColumn").ValidationText
End Sub
```

Note I added "Or Is Null" to the rule else I would be stuck in the textbox if I deleted my input.
The validation rule in the database is: >=1 And <=10

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I've met this problem too. I find `Me.Undo` works, in which `Me` refers to the form.

If you have to do some related operation with `Undo`, e.g. to delete a file from hard disk like me, use the `Form_Undo` event.