# ComboBox empty/null throws error. How to "reset" field?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combobox in my form with a table-filled list as rowsource. When the user enters the field, changes something and delete it so that the combobox is empty I get the error "You tried to assign a null value to a variable that is not a variant data type".

The problem is that my combobox does not allow an empty string but i also cannot find an event in the combobox that fires before the error. So I cannot use Len or IsNull to catch the error. Currently I use this "work around" but it is non-specific as it uses the error event of the form not of the combobox:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
    Me.myField.Undo
    Response = acDataErrContinue
End Sub
```

Is there a better way to handle this issue?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717808/clear-required-not-null-bound-textbox). But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: Which exact line throws that error, because it is not an error related to the control or table, it is related to code. You would probably be best changing the variable type for the section of code.

Comment: There is no variable but a link between two tables to update a text field.

Comment: What does the link look like? How does it update the field?

Comment: The combobox references the id of one table to another. In my case the value becomes null and that's my problem

Comment: The reference must be somewhere. Where is it? What does it look like?

Answer (score 3):

As Remou indicated in the comments, the error is in response to what you are doing after a new value is entered into the combobox.   Check the combobox events.    If you don't mind about the type and want to use null values, you can change your variable to a Variant type.  If you are using an actual data type such as string or integer then use the NZ() function to screen out nulls.

For example, if you want to assign an empty string to a string variable if the combobox is null then you can do:

```
dim s as string
s = nz(me.combobox,"")
```

As for firing before the error - somewhere in your code you already have the offending code that is causing the error.  You need to locate that.    More information will be required from you in order to provide a more detailed and specific answer.

Comment: That is certainly a fuller answer :)

Comment: It is definitly the link. I refer to an integer (id) with the null value.

Comment: Forgive me if you are aleady aware of this - just thought I'd cover the basics:
You could try changing the table relationship (link) to 1:1 (no arrow between tables).   This means that if Table1's key is "55" and Table2 does not contain 55 - then the record from Table1 will not show.  If you do a one to many relationship (Arrow on the second table only), then if there is no "55" in Table2, you'd see the contents of table1 but a Null for every record in table2.

Answer (score 3):

It's an undocumented Microsoft "Feature" designed to drive you crazy. And the people who tell you "look in your code", "somewhere in your code" don't know what they are talking about.

Two workarounds.  Change the underlying field in the table to allow nulls, OR, and I think this is the best way, change your combo to an unbound control and set the underlying field in the AfterUpdate event.

Comment: Sadly, this is the correct answer.  The error message makes it seem like a code problem, but it's not.  It's just one of the many cases in which the developer has to decide whether it's worth it to give the user a better experience at the cost of having to code around Access' intended behaviors.

Comment: Or, you can trap the error in the Form_Error event and set Response = 0 and handle how you choose.